# how to give required in google captcha

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

My PHP:

```
include_once ('db.php');

$capt_err = '';
$error = 0;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    if (!$captcha) {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("please check the captcha!");';

        // echo 'window.location.href="#mymodal";';

        echo '</script>';
        exit();
    }
    else {
        $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6LcoHioTAAAAAHvJ0FIRLC-VWVmpBSs_-7igEkXh&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    }

    if ($response . success == false) {
        echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
    }
    else {
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO vibodha_feedback (`id`,`name`,`email`,`phone`,`message`,`date`) VALUES('','$name','$email','$phone','$message',now())");
        echo "<script>" . "alert('Your Message has been sucessfully sent.')" . "</script>";
    }
}

// header('location:testimonials.php');
```

My HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"  method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
        <label for="mail">Email:</label>    
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
        <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
        <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone" required>
        <label for="message">Message:</label>   
        <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LewHioTAAAAANGO-VChqdjsoZARTVOxsrgPW6T8"></div>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Send!</button>
</form>
```

My JavaScript:
the script is default for g-recapcha(google),the google intergrate only recaptcha option..not to give required option.

i wrote validation in php code.the captcha is empty alert will come(refer php code)

the above three parts in my code..i give required in div class,,,the div not taken,then how to give required in captcha.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 <input type="text" class="inputcontact" id="captcha_contact" placeholder="Cod securitate" name="captcha" onchange="isEmpty('captcha_contact', 'hiba-captcha_contact')">
                <div id="error-captcha_contact"><span style="font-size: 8px;"></span></div>
```

JS file:

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#contact_send').click(function () {
var minden_ok = true;
             if (minden_ok == true) {
                    minden_ok = isEmpty('captcha_contact', 'error-captcha_contact');
                }
 if (minden_ok == true) {
    //your code here
  }
        });



function isEmpty(ID, errorID) {
var value= jQuery('#' + ID).val();
if (value.length > 0) {
    jQuery("#" + errorID).hide("slow");
    jQuery("#" + ID).css("border-color", "");
    return true;
} else {
    jQuery("#" + errorID + " span:first").text("Please fill !");
    jQuery("#" + ID).css("border-color", "red");
    jQuery("#" + errorID).show("slow");
    jQuery("#" + ID).focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Botond hai,,this is not work,,,then where to put this.

Comment: Check now. I added the html content and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

like

```
include_once ('db.php');

$capt_err = '';
$error = 0;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
       if($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']=='') 
       {
       echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("please check the captcha!");';

        // echo 'window.location.href="#mymodal";';

        echo '</script>';
        exit();
       }

    else {
        $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6LcoHioTAAAAAHvJ0FIRLC-VWVmpBSs_-7igEkXh&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    }

    if ($response . success == false) {
        echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
    }
    else {
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO vibodha_feedback (`id`,`name`,`email`,`phone`,`message`,`date`) VALUES('','$name','$email','$phone','$message',now())");
        echo "<script>" . "alert('Your Message has been sucessfully sent.')" . "</script>";
    }
}

// header('location:testimonials.php');
```

Comment: i dont understand it!

Comment: sir i was put on your code in my code ,,but didn't work,,,,,,